# Reading memory from a given address - MIPS

Tags: mips

I'm new to MIPS so I'm confused about some things. My question is if I have a value entered when the program first compiles and that the value is an address (0x10010040) which is stored in a label. How do I access the address stored in the label and not the actual address of the label?

```
.data 
input: 
.asciiz 
prompt: 
.asciiz "Enter the address  " 
prompt2:
.asciiz "Filling some memory aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccc


.text                  
.globl main  

main:

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

li $v0, 8 
li $a1, 32
la $a0, input
syscall
```

Been stuck on this for way too long. I tried lw instead of la, fooled around a bit, and just got errors. Using the address 0x10010040 should point to 1650614882. But instead it just points to the address where input is at which is 0x1001000. I know it's because I'm loading the address of input instead of loading the value of input as an address, which is my question on how to do.

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Labels don't store anything, there just constants with names that refer to some address. I'm guessing what you mean is how to get the data stored at an address and then use that as an address. Like a double pointer in C.

To do that, you would `lw` the data from the address (at the label) into a register (we'll call it `A`), then use `lw` again with A as your `src`, the data retrieved with the second `lw` is the data you want.